# Django - Extract hash tags from a post and save them all in a many-to-one relation

Tags: python, django

So I have this code below that when a user submits a post it extracts all the hash tags from it then creates a new entry in the hash tag table and also creates a new reference in the HashTagsInPost table so people can search posts by hash tags. My primary concerns lay in the Views.py file.

**Problems:**

1. I don't think it's good to iterate over the list of hash tags pulled out and doing a .get() call to see if exists then if it doesn't create it. There should be a better way to do this.
2. Since HashTagsInPost is a one-to-many relation, I don't really know how to store that lists of Hash Tags as the hash_tag attribute in the HashTagsInPost attribute. Do I just pass a list of HashTag objects?

Views.py

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        post_body = request.data['body']
        post_obj = serializer.save()
        hash_tags_list = extract_hashtags(post_body)

        for ht in hash_tags_list:
            try:
                ht_obj = HashTags.objects.get(pk=ht)
            except HashTags.DoesNotExist:
                ht_obj = HashTags.objects.create(hash_tag=ht)
            
            HashTagsInPost.objects.create(hash_tag=ht_obj, post_id=)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Models.py

```
class HashTags(models.Model):
    hash_tag = models.CharField(max_length=140, primary_key=True)  

class Post(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator_id", db_index=True)
    goal_id = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=511)

class HashTagsInPost(AbstractBaseModel):
    hash_tag = models.ForeignKey(HashTags, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    post_id = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly from your use case a `Post` can be related to multiple `HashTags` (**note**: model names should ideally be singular) objects. Whereas with your current modelling a post can have only one hashtag. To model a [many to many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) you should use a [`ManyToManyField` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) which will internally make a junction table having foreign keys to the two related tables:

```
class HashTags(models.Model):
    hash_tag = models.CharField(max_length=140, primary_key=True)  


class Post(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator_id", db_index=True)
    goal_id = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=511)
    # Add a m2m with HashTags
    hash_tags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTags, related_name='posts')
```

Now for your problem of getting / creating the tag, you can use the [`get_or_create` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        post_body = request.data['body']
        post_obj = serializer.save()
        hash_tags_list = extract_hashtags(post_body)
        hash_tags = [HashTags.objects.get_or_create(hash_tag=ht)[0] for ht in hash_tags_list]
        post_obj.hash_tags.set(hash_tags)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: the reason I have a separate table for hash tags referencing posts is so that I can search posts by hash tags in them. If I have a many-to-many I have to search through each row in the table's hash_tags field for a match.

Comment: @user8714896 You can filter quite easily for posts having some hash tags, e.g.: `Post.objects.filter(hash_tags=some_hash_tag)`, `Post.objects.filter(hash_tags__in=hash_tags_list)`

Comment: isn't that a lot slower than having a separate table?

Comment: @user8714896 what do you mean? A `ManyToManyField` does create a separate table which has a foreign key to both the related tables, you can modify your original solution and use a `ForeignKey` instead of `OneToOneField` to achieve the same. You can also specify a `through` model if you want to store more information in the intermediate model. Please go through the linked documentation for better understanding.

Comment: hmm I was told otherwise pretty insistently and accused of engineering "bad design" cause I originally did have your suggestion implemented, but I do remember that ManyToManyField does generate another table automatically so you maybe correct.

Comment: I guess the person being toxic was insisting the methodology I posted is faster for querying, because it's one to many and you query on the hash tag rather than all rows with that hash tag in the many-to-many table.

Comment: @user8714896 a one to many doesn't even suit your use case though, you _want_ a m2m relationship. As for speed concerns don't worry, Django automatically creates a database index for foreign keys so it should be quick to filter on these.

Comment: Hi @AbdulAzizBarkat I've used what you've suggested but I'm stuck at this error here

```django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "messaging_message_hash_tags" violates foreign key constraint "messaging_message_ha_hashtag_id_068959e9_fk_messaging"
DETAIL:  Key (hashtag_id)=((<HashTag: HashTag object (skills)>, True)) is not present in table "messaging_hashtag".
```

Comment: @AbhishekAN my bad, `get_or_create` returns a tuple of `(object, created)`, check the edit that should fix the error (Just added a `[0]` after `.get_or_create(hash_tag=ht)`)